# Configuring two interfaces problem

Tags: networking, server, internet

I got this issue:

I'm connected to internet using WLAN but i need to be connected to two servers, these servers are not connecteds to internet.

I did this, i used a switch, the problem is when I connect the cable. I can do ping to the servers but i lost the WLAN connection, I have configured both conexions but I'm sure I'm missing something, please help me. Thanks

My apologies for my english.

Comment: So you're connection to the internet with WiFi and to your LAN with (Ethernet) cable? If so it may work if you disable the "connect automatically..." for the LAN connection. Not sure though because I never used such configuration.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, i couldn't have two gateway, so i left lan ethernet withot gateway  and it worked! i got internet with WLAN and i got acces to the servers